# How to create the background for a LED text scroller in Android?

Tags: android, text, led, scroller

I want to create a background exactly like these two pictures:

[image]

[image]

Currently I have the text scrolling horizontally with a special LED-like font, however my background is just pure black. I'm not sure how to make the background LED-like.

Comment: Did you get answer? Have you created this app?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is perfect except few things below

You need curve less fonts, get some from here : www.1001fonts.com/led-fonts.html

And let's assume one LED as one pixel so you need to move your text one pixel at a time, it means you need to move your text same as the size of one LED. It should not be smooth otherwise it will not look like LED text, anyway if you would like to make it smooth then increase speed little bit.

Comment: Yes but my question is how do I get the small dots similarly to those backgrounds? My background is currently just black so it doesn't really look like a LED.

Comment: Ok, got it, there are two solutions for this a simple one with illusion and other one will require more work with animation in android.
**Simple** : Make an image just like image you posted which has LED written in it, and move it just as size of one pixel in it, it will look like LED.
**Not Simple** : Work with android animation and create LED pixels and change colors of pixels just as those letters would move.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following image as my friend has created.

[image]

Hope it will helps you.